# I Want to convert Speech to Text with Microsoft.Speech

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, windows-api-code-pack

Currently I attempted Speech to text with 
System.Speech and Microsoft.Speech

what I can do is only with Microsoft.Speech because System.Speech doesn't work if default language is not English.

First, I tried to use this code to get text from my voice.

```
public void Recognize()
    {
        using ( SpeechSynthesizer Synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer() )
        {
            // Text To Speech
            Synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            //Synthesizer.Speak( "Test" );

            using ( SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine() )
            {
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>( OnSpeechRecognized );
                recognizer.LoadGrammarCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadGrammarCompletedEventArgs>( OnLoadGrammarCompleted );
                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                recognizer.LoadGrammar( new Grammar( "Resources/Grammar.xml" )
                {
                    Enabled = true
                } );

                Console.WriteLine( "Recognize()" );

                RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 3 ) );
                if ( result != null )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Result => " + result.Text );
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Text is not on list" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and I noticed that if the sentence( or word ) in my speech doesn't contained in List in Grammar Items, it'll not applied on result.

so I searched about this problem and finally found this code.

```
public Grammar GrammarWithDictation()
    {
        GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
        builder.Append( "begin" );
        builder.AppendDictation( "spelling" );
        builder.Append( "end" );
        Grammar grammarWithDictation = new Grammar( builder );
        grammarWithDictation.Name = "Grammar with Dictation";

        return grammarWithDictation;
    }
```

So I applied it on my code like this.

```
public void Recognize()
    {
        using ( SpeechSynthesizer Synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer() )
        {
            // Text To Speech 
            Synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            //Synthesizer.Speak( "Test" );

            using ( SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine() )
            {
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>( OnSpeechRecognized );
                recognizer.LoadGrammarCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadGrammarCompletedEventArgs>( OnLoadGrammarCompleted );
                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                //recognizer.LoadGrammar( new Grammar( "Resources/Grammar.xml" )
                //{
                //    Enabled = true
                //} );

                recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync( GrammarWithDictation() );

                Console.WriteLine( "Recognize()" );

                RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 3 ) );
                if ( result != null )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Result => " + result.Text );
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "No Results." );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and it doesn't work.

So this is the main point of this long article.

How can I get whole sentence in my speech with Microsoft.Speech?

is it possible? or do I need to use other things to do this?

Comment: `Enabled = false`?

Comment: @KlausGütter that's my mistake. I tested with Enabled = true at first code. and it doesn't effective for getting whole sentence to text.